# using std::map gives warning: dereferencing pointer ‘<anonymous>’ does break strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++, linux

I've reduced a case to the code shown below here.
When compiling, this gives the following:

```
$ g++  -std=c++0x -O2 -Wall t.cpp
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:20: warning: dereferencing pointer ‘<anonymous>’ does break strict-aliasing rules
t.cpp:19: warning: dereferencing pointer ‘<anonymous>’ does break strict-aliasing rules
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:175: note: initialized from here
```

**What is this warning telling me ? What can I do about it ?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct TimeKey {

    uint64_t time_stamp;
    uint64_t msg_no;

    TimeKey(uint64_t tstamp, uint64_t no) :
        time_stamp(tstamp),
        msg_no(no)
    {}  

    bool operator < (const TimeKey &other) const 
    {   
        if (time_stamp == other.time_stamp)  //line 19
            return msg_no < other.msg_no;    //line 20
        else
            return time_stamp < other.time_stamp;
    }   
};

template <typename T>
class TimeBuffer {
public:
    uint64_t counter;
    std::map<TimeKey, T> messages;
    void AddMsg(uint64_t tstamp, T val) {
        messages[TimeKey(tstamp, counter++)] = val;
     }   
};  

int main(void)
{
    TimeBuffer<int> messages;
    messages.AddMsg(123456, 1); 
}
```

Note, this is on RHEL 6.3, which comes with gcc 4.4.6

Comment: Can't reproduce using gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: Which are lines 19 and 20?

Comment: Can't reproduce using gcc 4.6.3

Comment: @OliCharlesworth line 19 is `if (time_stamp == other.time_stamp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known (and fixed) compiler bug, see [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39390) and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42087). You should update your toolchain.

Comment: Though, upgrading the toolchain is easier said than done(without also upgrading the OS), and creates a maintenance burden in keeping production machines updated with a new and unsupported runtime...

Comment: I know, but using a two years old version for new functionalities (`-std=c++0x`) that is unsupported upstream won't help either :)